# Contenteditable property not working after adding button

Tags: html, css

I want to create a `contenteditable` `div` where user can put some comment. I use this

```
<div id="uploadcomment" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

This works fine I can write anything in  it now.

But when I try to add a submit button in it (I have to make button `contenteditable:false` because `contenteditable` is inherited property and it we automatically apply to button as well)

But now I can't write anything in it.

https://jsfiddle.net/amok08yg/1/

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want something like that :)

```css
body{background:gray}
.input_wrapper {
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  width:300px; 
  height:auto;
  margin-left:40px; 
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
  padding: 12px 6px 6px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}
#uploadcomment { 
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom:1px solid lightgray;
  font-size:1.1em;
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  height: 100px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 6px);
  float: right;
  }
#uploadcomment:active, #uploadcomment:focus {
  outline: none;
}
#submitcomment {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 6px;
  float: right;
  line-height: 160%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="input_wrapper">
  <textarea id="uploadcomment" placeholder="Describe yourself here..."></textarea>
  <button id="submitcomment"contenteditable="false">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
```